# Doctrine ORM custom persist / get entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm

I have an existing database made and currently used by a Drupal project. I need to write an app using Doctrine and this database.

I'd like to use the Doctrine ORM, but I cannot change the Database schema and it is kind of unintuitive (Drupal has kind of one table per data to store...).

Is there a way to tell Doctrine the SQL to store and read every attribute of my entities ?

Otherwise I will use Doctrine DBAL, but the simplicity of the entities interests me a lot.

Comment: do you have an example of the table structure?

Comment: I can't give you mine, but here is a very similar example from Drupal website https://www.drupal.org/files/er_db_schema_drupal_7.png
Note the node and field_data_field_* tables that contains a lot of the data I care about.

Comment: It should be easily possible to map that structure into Doctrine Entities.
Take a look at the Documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: I think there's even a tool which will analyse your DB structure and give you some appropriate Doctrine Entities, but I can't remember the name

Comment: https://www.skipper18.com/en/frameworks/doctrine2 there it is.

Comment: I could map every Drupal table on a Doctrine entity and set associations, but I want to use the ORM to use domain entities (like Article, Car, News...). And each field of these entities is stored in a separate SQL Table. I can't see how I can map one entity to multiple tables in the Doctrine documentation.